# Convert this NodeJs socket connection to Python

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, sockets

I am trying to replicate the following NodeJS code (I'm not really that familiar with Javascript type languages) into Python using the socket module:

```
function sendCommand(code, cb) {
        var commandBytes = [4,1,0,0,0,0, Math.floor(224 + (code/16)), code % 16];

        var client = net.connect({
            host: host,
            port: port || 49160
        });

        var l = 12;
        client.on('data', function(data) {
            clearTimeout(connectTimeoutTimer)
            // Clear timeout
            if (data.length < 24) {
                client.write(data.slice(0, l))
                l = 1;
            } else {
                client.write(new Buffer(commandBytes), function() {
                    commandBytes[1]=0;
                    client.write(new Buffer(commandBytes), function() {
                        client.destroy();
                        cb(null)
                    });
                });
            }
        });
```

I've figured out the basics, which is opening and closing the connection as so:

```
import socket

s = socket.socket()        
host = '192.168.1.157'
port = 49160

s.connect((host, port))
s.close()
```

...however I am not sure how to replicate the line:

```
var commandBytes = [4,1,0,0,0,0, Math.floor(224 + (code/16)), code % 16];
```

I realise that this is an 8 bit byte (the value of code comes from a dictionary furter down in the code I am converting), however I am not sure of the required syntax to pass this over to the IP address of my target machine.

Can anyone assist, please?

Comment: It's not much different, except python supports pure integer arithmetic. '//' is the integer division operator, so `Math.floor(224 + (code/16))` reduces to a simpler `224 + code // 16`. You can construct a `bytes` object simply by `bytes([4,1,0,0,0,0, 224 + code // 16, code % 16])` and then send this with `s.send()`

Comment: so when i print my output it looks like this: [4, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 227, 5]...is that what i should be sending, or does it need joining or something into 4100002275?

Comment: See my previous comment.

Comment: hi. what i mean though is 'data = bytes([4,1,0,0,0,0, 224 + 53 // 16, 53 % 16])
print data' gives me an output of '[4, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 227, 5].'...is that right for a byte output?

Comment: Are you using python2 or python3? I assumed python3

Comment: no, sorry...i am on 2.7...

Comment: Ah, well I don't work on python2 anymore so I don't know for sure.